# Java UnsatisfiedLinkError while native library is found

Tags: linux, java

I have a Java applet which allows me to access local storage in remote server. It works fine under Windows(IE 7.0.5730.13, Java SE 1.6.0.05). According to Java Console it downloads the native library for Java Native Interface:

```
ClientInterface::downloadLib: downloaded C:\Documents and Settings\user\IBM\10.10.10.65\remotedrive3d.dll in 1 attempts.
Initializing RemoteDisk v2.2
```

..and I'm able to access local storage devices:

[image: local storage devices under Windows]

Under Linux using *OpenJDK 1.8.0_121* and *IcedTea-Web 1.6.2* it also downloads the native library:

```
ClientInterface::downloadLib: downloaded /root/IBM/10.10.10.65/libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3 in 1 attempts.
```

However, it fails to run with an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` error-message:

```
Initializing RemoteDisk v2.2
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /root/IBM/10.10.10.65/libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: VirtualDrive.PassThroughCommand.GetSupportedDevices()LVirtualDrive/SupportedDevices;
        at VirtualDrive.PassThroughCommand.GetSupportedDevices(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.asm.remotedisk.RemoteDisk.buildDriveList(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.asm.remotedisk.RemoteDisk.start(Unknown Source)
        at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:476)
        at sun.applet.AppletViewerPanelAccess.run(AppletViewerPanelAccess.java:84)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

..and I'm not able to access local storage devices:

[image: local storage devices under Linux]

When I start the Firefox using `strace -f`, then I can clearly see that `libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` file is accessed. For example:

```
[pid  6741] open("/root/IBM/10.10.10.65/libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 48
[pid  6741] read(48, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\3\0\1\0\0\0\334S\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 52) = 52
[pid  6741] close(48)
```

This `/root/IBM/10.10.10.65/libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` seems to contain strings like `GetSupportedDevices`:

```
root@s:~/IBM/10.10.10.65# strings libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3 | grep -i GetSupportedDevices
Java_VirtualDrive_PassThroughCommand_GetSupportedDevices
GetSupportedDevices
Java_VirtualDrive_PassThroughCommand_GetSupportedDevices
root@s:~/IBM/10.10.10.65#
```

Is the proprietary native library `libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` for Linux operating system probably broken? Is it possible that it is not compatible with OpenJDK? How to debug this further?

Comment: What does `file libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` say?

Comment: Get a copy of `libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` and run `ldd` against it to see what other libraries it depend on.

Comment: this may be in case the library is already loaded by your application and the application tries to load it again, the  `UnsatisfiedLinkError` will be thrown by the JVM see, https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/

Comment: @omajid `file libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` says `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`. @alvits `ldd` says that it is `not a dynamic executable`. When I inspect the `ldd` script, then in my system, where `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` and `/libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2` are missing, it simply runs the `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --verify /root/IBM/10.10.10.65/libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` command which exits with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is issue for http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=IcedTea-Web not stack overflow.  As ITW developer, I will need to help with debugging a bit.

From the trace is clear architecture mishmash.  I would bet your windows are 32b, but linux is (for sure) 64b machine. For some reason, ITW is downloading 32b version of your RemoteDrive library. 32b library *should* work on 64b system,  but you need also 32b depndencies (and most likely also 32b java). Do you have them all?

If above is completly true, then it is bug i ITW, or jdk itslef. But I'm betting for above.

So: try 32 jdk, try various 32b depndencies, if not working, then please submit bug to ITW

HtH
  J.

Comment: Maybe this 32 bit `libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` library is the only one provided by web application? In addition, as I understood it, this `libibmxrdisk.so.1.0.3` file is a native Linux executable, i.e it definitely needs 32 bit dependencies, but why should it need 32 bit JVM?

Comment: Why 32b jvm? Because processes can not do it.  On 64b system, process canbe 32b or 64b, but not combined. Generally you cannot load 32deps from 64b process (and of course vice versa)

Comment: See this example:  https://jvanek.fedorapeople.org/jniTest/   :  be sure you you run it from your CWD.   I create it on 64b fedora 24.  Java compiled by javac *.java ( so no magic here) but   CLibHelloWorld  in 64b folder commpiled like gcc -I /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/ -I /usr/lib/jvm/java/include/linux/ -Wall -fpic -g -c  CLibHelloWorld.c    && gcc -shared -o CLibHelloWorld.so   CLibHelloWorld.o , but in 32b folder  with  -m32  (so 32b library).

Comment: When I run /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc24.x86_64/jre/bin/java  HelloWorld  in 64b diretroy, it works fine. But when I run the same in 32b dir, you will get your exception.  In same way I can run /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-1.b12.fc24.i686/jre/bin/java in 32b directory, but go mad in 64b directory. HTH. J.